# How to improve the style of this LaTeX line

Tags: equations

I have the following line in TeX and my problem is that the `backslash` is too small and the text under the `bigcup` becomes very cumbersome:

```
$$ess \ supp(f) = W \ \backslash \bigcup_{\Omega \subset W 
\text{ open and }  f|_{\Omega}=0 \text{ a.e.}} \Omega$$
```

Is there any way to remedy those difficulties?

Comment: Is it an option to have the descriptive text `open and` and `a.e.` outside of the equation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think a combination of (i) defining "ess sup" to be an "operator" (so that it's set in the upright font shape) and (ii) using both `\mathclap` (from the `mathtools` package) and `\substack` (from the `amsmath` package, which is loaded automatically by `mathtools`) may achieve what you want. Oh, and don't use `\backslash` -- I believe `\setminus` is more appropriate in this context.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\esssupp}{ess\,supp} % "essential support"
\setlength\textwidth{3in} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\noindent before:
\[
ess \ supp(f) = W \ \backslash \bigcup_{\Omega \subset W 
\text{ open and }  f|_{\Omega}=0 \text{ a.e.}} \Omega
\]

\noindent after:
\[
\esssupp(f) = W \setminus 
\bigcup_{ \mathclap{\substack{\Omega \subset W \text{\,open,} \\
                              f|_{\Omega}=0 \text{ a.e.}}}} \Omega
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* As pointed out by @Manuel in a comment, you may also be interested in using the `\smashoperator` macro (instead of `\mathclap`):

[image]

```
\[
\esssupp(f) = W \setminus 
\smashoperator[r]{\bigcup_{ \substack{\Omega \subset W \text{\,open,}  \\ 
                                      f|_{\Omega}=0 \text{ a.e.}}}} \Omega
\]
```

Comment: `mathtools` also offers `\smashoperator[lr]{…}` for this kind of occasions.

Comment: @Manuel - Thanks for this. I've posted an addendum to the answer to provide an application of this very useful macro.

Comment: It is the essential support, so the operator name should end with to p's.

Comment: @Mico: The horizontal spacing cant be improved (in my opinion) if one asks to use `\scriptscriptstyle` in each line of the substack.

Comment: @egreg - thanks for pointing out this mis-interpretation. I'll fix the write-up right away.

Comment: @Bernard - Your visual acuity may be a lot better than mine, but I find it preferable to typeset only material that's clearly of secondary importance (such as subscripts, indices, etc) in scriptscriptstyle. That, or provide a free magnifying lens to all readers... For the case at hand, it may be better to set the entire material to the right of the union symbol (in texstyle), as egreg has done in his answer.

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion there's no way to make this beautiful with such long conditions below the union symbol. I'd prefer something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\esssupp}{ess\,supp}
\newcommand\tae{\unskip\text{ a.e.}}

\begin{document}
\noindent before:
\[
ess \ supp(f) = W \ \backslash \bigcup_{\Omega \subset W
\text{ open and }  f|_{\Omega}=0 \text{ a.e.}} \Omega
\]
after:
\[
\esssupp(f) = W \setminus
\bigcup\{\,\Omega: \text{$\Omega \subset W$ open, $f|_{\Omega}=0$ \tae}\,\}
\]
Alternative:
\[
\esssupp(f) = W \setminus
\bigcup_{
  \mspace{-6mu}
  \substack{\Omega\subset W\text{ open}\\f|_{\Omega}=0\tae}
  \mspace{-15mu}
}\Omega
\]
\end{document}
```

In the alternative way, the conditions should not go too much below the `\setminus` symbol and the final `\Omega` should be somewhat on the right of the conditions. But the preferred way should be with the set notation.

[image]